# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, multiple-monitors

I've got dual boot going OK. I can select which OS I want in the Grub menu between Ubuntu and Windows 10, but when I boot into Ubuntu after booting going into Windows, there is a pop up saying "Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error" and any screen settings I had are gone (monitors flipped back to wrong side, desktop picture removed).

Then I run into no end of issues and things that don't work.

I have reinstalled Ubuntu twice, and it works fine until I boot Eindows, and then go back into Ubuntu, at which point this starts happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Ubuntu for sure, but I can say for certain that it has nothing to do with Windows.  Booting into Windows doesn't mount the Linux partitions or change anything.

Comment: Do you mean that if you reboot or shutdown and then keep booting into Ubuntu instead of Windows then nothing will go wrong?

Comment: Exactly.  After a fresh reinstall, if I just boot into ubuntu over and over nothing happens, but once I go into windows and then back into ubuntu the issue occurs.  Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you shut down or restart the Windows OS properly before booting your computer into Ubuntu. If you're sharing your hard drive across both partitions, it does not read correctly if Windows is not restarted or shut down correctly.